# Custom notification view RemoteView does not show up

Tags: android, android-notifications, androidx

I have created a notification using a simple layout with textview and imageview. But after calling notificationManager.notify(...); does not show the notification.

Following is the code i have created

```
// Create notificationmanager instance
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

// Setting the channelid if versioncode is greater than Oreo's
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

// Creating remote views for the notifications
            RemoteViews notificationLayoutCollapsed = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout_collapsed);
            RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout_expanded);

// Passing the intent 
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);-

   // setting the flags
 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

// Style MOST LIKELY ISSUE IS HERE
     NotificationCompat.Style style = new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle();

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContent(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationLayoutCollapsed)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
                    .setStyle(style)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder1.build());
```

I have also tried using the `style = new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle();`

But when i set the style as `BigText` or `BigPicture` and do not set  the customcontentview i do see the notification.

**Edit**

I have used both `v4.NotificationCompat`, `androidx.NotificationCompat`
Problem is in my code, I think some step is missing. Pls help.

Comment: custom notification layout only supports android component, then not support custom view, androidx, android support library or any library.

Comment: The layout contains android only components like textview, button and imageview and no custom component is added. 
setCustomContentView and setCustomBigContentView are the methods which accepts the remoteViews.

Comment: @Alireza Tizfahm Fard your answer got me towards right direction.Thanks for that.
Remoteviews only supports LinearLayout, GridLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLyout.
I was using ConstraintLayout. Which was resulting in notification not being shown.

Comment: your welcome, that's what I mean